# what to do after terminal showed file not found?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I just wrote this and saved it.

```
public class UseArgument
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Hi, ");
        System.out.print(args[0]);
        System.out.println(". How are you?");
    }
}
```

The file name is UseArgument.java, 
and I checked the code with my java book. 
Somehow terminal showed file not found after I type Javac UseArgument.java
what is wrong here?

Comment: The compiler can't find your code. Make sure you're in the right directory

Comment: Did you check if you had that command in corrct directory?

Comment: Once I typed pwd, it shows /Users/sun/Michael.java, and that's my file on desktop. Should I make it into /Users/sun/Michael.java/Desktop ?

Answer (score 0):

Saw your comment that once you typed pwd it returned /Users/sun/Michael.java. You sure, that's where your file is present. Try command "ls" to see the contents inside this dir and see whether UserArgument.java is present or not

I think you are not inside the correct dir. Change working dir to the path where UserArgument.java is present.

You need to have one file called UserArgument.java as your class name is UserArgument.

Thanks

Comment: `Michael.java` is a directory, not a file.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time and answer my question! I just figured it out!